# How to make a Windows 10 application that overlaps on the taskbar?

Tags: java, windows-10, exe

I made a java program, exported it from Ecplise as a runnable jar, and then used an app called "Launch4j" to wrap it with an icon into a .exe

This picture shows another app I have on the left. It has 2 instances open and you can see they overlap on the taskbar. My app is the little house, and the two java icons on the right are 2 instances of my app. How can I make my app overlap on the original icon like the other app?

[image: 2 instances of an app that overlaps and 2 instances of my app that do not overlap]

Edit:

Additionally, in task manager, my app opens as "Java(TM) Platform SE Binary" instead of the .exe file as you can see eclipse does.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that windows uses the `AppId` to determine what buttons to stack on the taskbar.

So you would need to tell windows the `AppId`, which I don't think is very easy with `Launch4j`.

Instead you might try Inno Setup, here's a good answer explaining the [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22321923/2442526).

Inno Setup should include examples which tell you how to specify your `AppId` among other things.

Comment: That did not help (but it was nice that it would install in a custom folder so thanks for that).

Comment: @Tirmulus Rats. There must be *some* property of the application that's used to determine how to stack them on the taskbar. If we can just find out what that property is then you still might be able to configure it with Inno Setup.

Comment: Since I know almost nothing about this, I worry I just used Inno Setup incorrectly. I pointed Inno Setup to my .exe file. Where does the AppId come into play? Does Inno Setup change the .exe file?